# Angularjs search filter

Tags: angularjs, search

how to access the search model inside your header directive using angularJS

```
     <div header showprofile="false" >
        <div class="searchView col-xs-12">

                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search" />         
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divtop">
        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search" /> -->
        <div class="it-content col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div ng-repeat="it in itBatch.its | filter: search" class="visit-card">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to access the `search` model inside your header directive, is that right?

Comment: s that is what am trying for

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the model to the directive like this -

```
<div header showprofile="false" search="search">
    <div class="searchView col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search" />         
    </div>
</div>
```

> Update your directive to accept it

```
.directive('header', function() {
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.search, function(value) {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      showprofile: '=',
      search: '=',
    },
    link: link
  };
});
```

**UPDATE**
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd7gddbu/1/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please post your directive code and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Am trying to give search filter for my page in the header

Comment: Please check my updated answer, it's working fine for me.. https://jsfiddle.net/yd7gddbu/1/

Comment: @MadhumithaReddy what?